# How to prove this assign clause?

Tags: frama-c

```
/*@
  @ requires \valid(p);
  @ assigns \nothing;
*/
void foo(int *p)
{
    int *pb;
    pb = p;
    *pb = 1;
    return;
}

void main(){
    int a = 0;
    foo(&a);
    return;
}
```

As I understand the assigns clause for a function contract only works with the function's input variables.  So I make the assigns clause to nothing but then get yellow status with -wp.

```
frama-c -wp test1.c
[kernel] Parsing test1.c (with preprocessing)
[wp] Warning: Missing RTE guards
[wp] 3 goals scheduled
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_foo_assign_part2 : Unknown (Qed:4ms) (51ms)
[wp] Proved goals:    2 / 3
Qed:             2 
Alt-Ergo:        0  (unknown: 1)
```

How to prove foo() if assigns \nothing is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure of what you mean by "`assigns` [...] only works with the function's input variable". An `assigns` clause is supposed to give a superset of all memory locations that are allocated in both the pre- and post- states of the contract (there are specific clauses for handling dynamic (de)allocation) and that might be modified during the execution of the function (or the statement for a statement contract).

In particular, your function `foo` can't have an `assigns \nothing;` clause since it modifies the value of the location pointed to by `p`: you must have something like `assigns *p;`, which is easily proved by `frama-c -wp`.

Comment: You're right.  I can prove it now with `assigns *p;` instead of `assigns \nothing;`.  Like I said I was assumed that I can use assigns clause only on the input's variable that get modified within the function.  In this case I guess frama-c is smart enough to see that the value that indirectly pointed to by p get modified.  Need to read up more on assigns clause then.   Thanks for the answer.